# How can I remove selective stashes in git?

Tags: git, github, git-stash

I have the list of stashes and want to drop some of them selectively.

For my example, I want to **remove stash@{1}, stash@{3}, stash@{4}, stash@6}**

> $git stash list

```
stash@{1}: Tests On branch1-om: Test for #8
stash@{2}: WIP On branch1-om: WIP for #12
stash@{3}: Temp on branch1-om: 0a447303 Add Unit Tests for the HttpClient
stash@{4}: To delete stash: 233abc813c fix
stash@{5}: WIP on branchn-test-om: 4a42e4 WIP: Commit
stash@{6}: On branch-test-om: projects deleted/modified when rebuilt
stash@{7}: My configurations: Apply my local dev configurations
```

**My Current step is very repetitive:**

> $git stash drop stash@{1}
>
> $git stash list

```
stash@{1}: WIP On branch1-om: WIP for #12
stash@{2}: Temp on branch1-om: 0a447303 Add Unit Tests for the HttpClient
stash@{3}: To delete stash: 233abc813c fix
stash@{4}: WIP on branchn-test-om: 4a42e4 WIP: Commit
stash@{5}: On branch-test-om: projects deleted/modified when rebuilt
stash@{6}: My configurations: Apply my local dev configurations
```

> $git stash drop stash@{2}
>
> $git stash list

```
stash@{1}: WIP On branch1-om: WIP for #12
stash@{2}: To delete stash: 233abc813c fix
stash@{3}: WIP on branchn-test-om: 4a42e4 WIP: Commit
stash@{4}: On branch-test-om: projects deleted/modified when rebuilt
stash@{5}: My configurations: Apply my local dev configurations
```

> $git stash drop stash@{2}
>
> $git stash list

```
stash@{1}: WIP On branch1-om: WIP for #12
stash@{2}: WIP on branchn-test-om: 4a42e4 WIP: Commit
stash@{3}: On branch-test-om: projects deleted/modified when rebuilt
stash@{4}: My configurations: Apply my local dev configurations
```

> $git stash drop stash@{3}
>
> $git stash list

```
stash@{1}: WIP On branch1-om: WIP for #12
stash@{2}: WIP on branchn-test-om: 4a42e4 WIP: Commit
stash@{4}: My configurations: Apply my local dev configurations
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that removing stashes *from the top* renumbers them. But since you can remove them at any position, you don't need to act as if stashes have only stack-like access.

Drop them from the furthest, to keep the numbers intact:

```sh
for N in 6 4 3 1; do git stash drop stash@\{$N}; done
```

Comment: Note that recent versions of `git stash` let you use the number without the `stash@{...}` part, too. If your Git version predates 2.11, you'll need the longer form, though.

Comment: @torek: good to know! But the man page for version 2.24 still only shows the old syntax in examples, though it does mention the new syntax, and also power-user things like `stash@{2.hours.ago}`.

Comment: @9000 is the temp solution that we can take now... not approving as accepted answer as it doesn't completely provide the solution...

Comment: Yes, I changed my mind to go with this as solution, as of now, until git provides new APIs for bulk drop. Minor update as suggested by torek: "$ for N in 6 4 3 1; do git stash drop $N; done"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, git stash drop seems to not support multiple stash as parameters:

```sh
% git stash drop stash@{{0},{2}}
Too many revisions specified: 'stash@{0}' 'stash@{2}'
```

My best guess would be to do:

```sh
i=0; for s in 0 2; do git stash drop stash@{$((s-i))}; i=$((i+1)); done
```

Because git stash drop updates the stash index even if you don't look at the stash list (which is odd tbh)

EDIT: Although this is only if you want to remove them in ascending order, 9000's solution is way simpler otherwise.